# How to modify HScrollBar size of the inner selection rectangle?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with C# on .NET 4.0 using System.Windows.Forms.HScrollBar.

I would like to change the size of the inner selection rectangle as indicated by the red arrow.

[image: Inner scrolling rectangle of a HScrollbar]

I will give an example to explain my use case: I have a Dataset, let's say with 10.000 points, and I want to display
only an interval of them into a Chart, let's say 2.000 points.
I am drawing a System.Windows.Form.Panel with a Chart in the upper part and a HScrollBar in the bottom.

What I would like to achieve is that I could set the size of the inner rectangle of the
HScrollBar according to the interval I am using. In the example with 10.000 data points and an
interval of 2.000 points the size of the inner rectangle should be 1/5 of the total lenght of
the HScrollBar.

```cs
var sb = new HScrollBar();
sb.Minimum = 0;
sb.Maximum = totalNumOfPoints;
sb.SelectionSize = maxNumOfVisiblePoints;  // this property does not exists, is what I am looking for
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Wouldn't you just need the Value property + 2000 to get your range?  A panel has ScrollBars built in, just set the AutoScrollMinSize property and use the AutoScrollPosition property.

Comment: The ScrollBar does not scroll the panel itself, but the Chart (the Panel only contains the Chart and the Scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I figured out the correct name of what I was looking for that is
`Scroll Thumb`
as shown in [Scroll Bar Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpyZW.png)

Than I was able to find that in C# you cannot directly set the size of the
Scroll Thumb, but you have to play with `LargeChange` and `SmallChange`:

```
var sb = new HScrollBar();
sb.Minimum = 0;
sb.Maximum = totalNumOfPoints - 1;
sb.LargeChange = maxNumOfVisiblePoints;
```

A reference is [changing thumb size of horizontal scrollbar](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/875930-changing-thumb-size-horizontal-scrollbar)